# What is the non-asymptotic upper bound for the leading eigenvector of the random matrix?

Tags: probability, analysis, random-matrices

Fix a Gaussian random matrix $A$ with $E[A_{ij}]=0$ for $i, j=1,\dots n$ and $E[A_{ij}^2]=\frac{1}{n}$. Let $v_1$ be the leading eigenvector of $A$. What is the non-asymptotic upper bound for $v_1$, that is something like
$$
P(\|v_1\|_2\ge t)\le e^{-\alpha t}
$$

Is there any reference for this tail probability?

Comment: Are the entries independent?

Comment: @dmh Yes, we can assume that.

Comment: I believe you want this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306253/bounding-the-spectral-norm-of-a-gaussian-random-matrix